# cling - prevent exiting when piping in data

Tags: c++, cling

I'm adding a `repl:` option using [cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) to my makefile which will drop me into a repl to play around with my current project. I created an `cling_init.cpp` which pulls in all the headers and does some basic setup.

Then in my `Makefile`:

```
repl:
    cat cling_init.cpp | cling -std=c++11 // etc ...
```

the issue is that when I pipe in the contents, cling exits after evaluating it. I've looked for an option to pass a file to cling but I can't seem to find anything.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Robᵩ read eval print loop

Comment: The problem is that your shell will close the input stream when it reaches EOF, which to _cling_ is indistinguishable from if you were inputting the data manually then typed Ctrl+D at the end. You'll need some approach that isn't pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! You can pass a source file the same way as a library `-l`.

```
repl:
    cling -std=c++11 -lcling_init.cpp -llibpq.so -lliblog4cxx.so //etc ...
```

Fyi you also need to put the entire library names for it to work.

For doing additional setup I had to use a static block:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ClingInitialize {
  ClingInitialize () {
    std::cout << "initialize" << std::endl;
  }
};

static ClingInitialize staticBlock;
```